# Layout transition with subpass dependencies not working

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, 3d, vulkan

So I'm trying to implement shadow mapping in vulkan, but when I begin the renderpass in the command buffer, the validation complains about the image layouts not being as expected. I'm using secondary command buffers for rendering and executing them in primary command buffer. I'm the subpass dependencies for the layout transitions between the renderpasses. Even though I use the dependencies, the validation still complains. I'm also unsure if the shadow mapping is incorrect because of the incorrect layouts. The shadow mapping should not be incorrect in the shader though. What could the cause of this be? I have tried checking the Sascha Willems shadow mapping example, but can not see why there is any problem.

**Render pass creation**

```
        AttachmentInfo depthAttachment;
        depthAttachment.p_AttachmentType = AttachmentType::Depth;
        depthAttachment.p_Format = VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM;
        depthAttachment.p_SampleCount = 1;// m_CurrentWindow->maxMSAASamples;
        depthAttachment.p_LoadOp = LoadOp::Clear;
        depthAttachment.p_StoreOp = StoreOp::Store;
        depthAttachment.p_StencilLoadOp = LoadOp::Null;
        depthAttachment.p_StencilStoreOp = StoreOp::Null;
        depthAttachment.p_InitialLayout = Layout::Undefined;
        depthAttachment.p_FinalLayout = Layout::DepthR;

        m_ShadowMapRenderPass.addAttachment(depthAttachment);

        VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
        dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
        dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
        dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
        dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
        dependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
        dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        dependency.dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

        m_ShadowMapRenderPass.m_Dependencies.push_back(dependency);

        dependency.srcSubpass = 0;
        dependency.dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
        dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
        dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
        dependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
        dependency.dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

        m_ShadowMapRenderPass.m_Dependencies.push_back(dependency);

        m_ShadowMapRenderPass.create();
```

**Validation error**

```
vkCmdExecuteCommands():: Executed secondary command buffer using VkImage 0x548d63000000080e[] 
(subresource: aspectMask 0x2 array layer 0, mip level 0) which expects layout 
VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL--instead, image current layout is 
VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL.
```

**Command buffer recording**

```
        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdBegin();

        // Shadow map render pass
        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdBeginRenderPass(m_ShadowMapRenderPass, SubpassContents::Secondary, m_ShadowMapFramebuffer);

        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdExecuteCommands(m_ShadowMapCommandBuffers);

        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdEndRenderPass();

        // Present render pass
        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdBeginRenderPass(m_DefaultRenderPass, SubpassContents::Secondary, p_FrameBuffer, m_CurrentWindow->getWindowSize());

        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdExecuteCommands(m_CommandBuffers);

        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdEndRenderPass();

        m_PrimaryCommandBuffers[p_Index].cmdEnd();
```

My shadow mapping is incorrect even though the shadow map is correct when viewing it with renderdoc.

Comment: What is `m_ShadowMapRenderPass.addAttachment(depthAttachment)` doing?

Comment: It just makes the VkAttachmentInfo and the Attachment ref. This will be used when i create the renderpass. The renderpass creation shouls be correct, through renderdoc i can see that all renderpass values are correct.

Comment: @PeterBjergert But which `layout` does it set in the reference?

Comment: VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL

Comment: I forgot to set the layout for the descriptor to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL. So know the validation does not complain anymore, but the shadow mapping still is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: For some reason the y value in the texture coordinates always are upside down, i just subtract it with one, this solves the shadow mapping issue.

Comment: The point of my comment was "Are you use addAttachment is populating something that ends up in `VkSubpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment` and not `VkSubpassDescription.pColorAttachments`.  Have you verified in the debugger that the subpass description looks correct in all regards before it's created?

Comment: Through renderdoc i can see that all values are correct and btw it works know.